# Find similar items from the array list in java

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have array list like below , from the list i have to find only apple, apple 1 and apple 2 and in the same way banana and banana 1.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("test");
list.add("apple");
list.add("banana");
list.add("apple 1");
list.add("apple 2");
list.add("fruits");
list.add("banana 1");
```

I tried the below code but I'm always getting all the values instead of the similar values as mentioned above

```
List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

for (String value: list) 
{
    if (list.contains(value)) 
    {
       resultList.add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the fails to do any research and show any effort and just looks for a piece of cake to scarf down.

Comment: It is very unclear what is your question (all I see is requirement, not question). So try to [edit] your post and show what have you tried till now and what stops you from finishing your task (what is the hard part).

Comment: @KickButtowski FYI You can just use "too broad" for "do my homework for me" questions, there are lots of ways to write any particular program, etc.

Comment: You achieve it by writing Java code.

Comment: @Rayyan It's because you check if each value in the list is contained within the list, which is always true. You want to check if each item contains the substring.

Comment: In this code `for (String value: list)` `value` is reference which holds current element **from** your list so `list.contains(value)` by definition must be true (unless list changed between you get this element and `if` test).

Comment: What do you think your code should do and why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the list checking if the item contains a desired substring:

```
for (String item: list) 
{
    if (item.split("\\s+")[0].equals("apple")) 
    {
        System.out.println(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am guessing that it is because this approach would also accept pineapple.

Comment: @Pshemo How about now?

Comment: Looks better, but I still don't know if it is what OP wants so I can't vote for your answer.

Comment: Could also be that someone detests the answering of such a question. Not me of course.

Comment: the value apple is not hard coded one that value  is part of the list, i need to loop through the list from that i have find similar items like i mentioned in OP

Comment: This does exactly that. It finds all the apple strings.

Comment: Whether this is correct depends on how you define "similar" but it's a valid answer.